# Why does this command to copy files in a for loop work in bash but not in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, for

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files with the same name, but in different subdirectories, to a single directory, changing the names to ones based on the paths to the original files. I use a for loop that does what I intend in bash, but behaves very oddly in zsh.

Command (linebreaks added for legibility):

```
for f in */Flavors/*/stuff1/filename.txt;
    do l=$(echo $f | cut -d'/' --output-delimiter '' -f1,3);
    dest=/stuff2/${l}.utf8.txt;
    echo $f $dest;
    cp -v -- $f $dest;
done
```

Output in zsh. I intend the output file names to be e.g. "EnglishAU.utf8.txt" but instead they are just "English", "French" and "Spanish". Note that the `echo` in the loop shows `$dest` containing the correct path, and then the `cp` uses the wrong one!

```
English/Flavors/AU/stuff1/filename.txt /stuff2/EnglishAU.utf8.txt
`English/Flavors/AU/stuff1/filename.txt' -> `/stuff2/English'
English/Flavors/UK/stuff1/filename.txt /stuff2/EnglishUK.utf8.txt
`English/Flavors/UK/stuff1/filename.txt' -> `/stuff2/English'
English/Flavors/US/stuff1/filename.txt /stuff2/EnglishUS.utf8.txt
`English/Flavors/US/stuff1/filename.txt' -> `/stuff2/English'
French/Flavors/CA/stuff1/filename.txt /stuff2/FrenchCA.utf8.txt
`French/Flavors/CA/stuff1/filename.txt' -> `/stuff2/French'
French/Flavors/FR/stuff1/filename.txt /stuff2/FrenchFR.utf8.txt
`French/Flavors/FR/stuff1/filename.txt' -> `/stuff2/French'
Spanish/Flavors/ES/stuff1/filename.txt /stuff2/SpanishES.utf8.txt
`Spanish/Flavors/ES/stuff1/filename.txt' -> `/stuff2/Spanish'
Spanish/Flavors/OT/stuff1/filename.txt /stuff2/SpanishOT.utf8.txt
`Spanish/Flavors/OT/stuff1/filename.txt' -> `/stuff2/Spanish'
```

As mentioned above, this works as intended in bash. What's zsh doing?

Comment: Could you please define »behaving very oddly«?  What's `zsh` doing what you're not expecting?

Comment: You could use `zmv`. Load it with `autoload -Uz zmv` and use it like that: `zmv -C '(*)/Flavors/(*)/stuff1.filename.txt' '/stuff2/${1}${2}.utf8.txt'`. `-C` invokes `cp` instead of the default `mv`, source patterns surrounded by parentheses are replaced in turn by `$1`, `$2` and so on, the patterns are alway treated as *EXTENDED_GLOB* patterns. See `zshcontrib(1)` for more information.

Comment: @Adapheon: Oh, that's really nice, pretty much exactly what I wish I had when I was working on this command. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasWiese: Was my explanation between the two code boxes inadequate somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because `cut` is outputting NULL characters in the output. You can't pass a program arguments which contain a null character (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020172/are-char-argv-arguments-in-main-null-terminated)).

In bash this works because bash can't handle NULL characters in strings, and it strips them out. Zsh is a bit more powerful, and it can handle NULL characters. However when it comes time to pass the string to the program, it still contains the null, which signals the end of the argument.

Let's look at this in detail.

```
$ echo 'English/Flavors/AU/stuff1/filename.txt' | cut -d'/' --output-delimiter '' -f1,3 | xxd
0000000: 456e 676c 6973 6800 4155 0a              English.AU.
```

Here we simulated one of your files, passing the path through `cut`. Notice the `xxd` output which has a NULL character between `English` and `AU`.

Now lets run through and simulate the rest of the script.

```
$ l=$(echo 'English/Flavors/AU/stuff1/filename.txt' | cut -d'/' --output-delimiter '' -f1,3)
$ dest=/stuff2/${l}.utf8.txt
$ echo "$dest" | xxd
0000000: 2f73 7475 6666 322f 456e 676c 6973 6800  /stuff2/English.
0000010: 4155 2e75 7466 382e 7478 740a            AU.utf8.txt.
```

Notice the NULL after the `English`. The `echo` displays it properly because `echo` is a shell built-in. If we use an external `echo`, it also exhibits the issue.

```
$ /bin/echo "$dest" | xxd 
0000000: 2f73 7475 6666 322f 456e 676c 6973 680a  /stuff2/English.
```

*P.S. You really should be quoting too :-)*

---

The solution is to not use `cut`, use `awk` instead.

```
$ echo 'English/Flavors/AU/stuff1/filename.txt' | awk -F/ '{ print $1$3 }' | xxd
0000000: 456e 676c 6973 6841 550a                 EnglishAU.
```

Comment: Chapéu! Nice answer, hadn't initially thought of this.

Comment: Great answer, well explained. One further question, though: _why_ are those NULLs in there? Is it because of the blank `--output-delimiter` option?

Comment: @valrus I would guess that it's deliberately coded so that if you pass an empty argument, you get a NULL delimiter. Just a guess though. Man page makes no mention of the behavior.

Comment: Yes, it case like me you wonder, it's not a bug, but an undocumented feature. The source of GNU `cut` (`--output-delimiter` is GNU only) does have code specific for that and a comment that says _Interpret --output-delimiter='' to mean
             'use the NUL byte as the delimiter.'_